# How do I start an unknown (but limited) number of lambda functions, each with an incremental port number, in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In effect, I want the opposite of this Makefile recipe:

```
.PHONY: stop-lambdas # Stop the lambdas.
stop-lambdas:
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory --makefile LastBuildMakefile report-build
    @echo ''
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory lambda-stopper
    @echo ''
lambda-stopper: $(patsubst %,-stop-%,$(LAMBDAS))
$(patsubst %,-stop-%,$(LAMBDAS)):
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory validate-lambda lambda="$(patsubst -stop-%,%,$@)"
    @echo "Start the lambda function in lambdas/$(patsubst -stop-%,%,$@)."
    @docker stop "lambda_$(patsubst -stop-%,%,$@)">/dev/null
    @echo ''
```

So far I've got:

```
.PHONY: start-lambdas # Get the lambdas up and running to allow you to make calls to them.
start-lambdas:
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory --makefile LastBuildMakefile report-build
    @echo ''
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory lambda-starter
    @echo ''
lambda-starter: $(patsubst %,-start-%,$(LAMBDAS))
$(patsubst %,-start-%,$(LAMBDAS)):
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory validate-lambda lambda="$(patsubst -start-%,%,$@)"
    @echo "Start the lambda function in lambdas/$(patsubst -start-%,%,$@)."
    @docker run --detach --name "lambda_$(patsubst -start-%,%,$@)" --publish XXXXXXX:8080 --rm "${CONTAINER_GROUP}/lambda_$(patsubst -start-%,%,$@):${LAST_CONTAINER_TAG_BRANCH}_${LAST_CONTAINER_TAG_VERSION}" > /dev/null
    @echo ''
```

The one bit I can't work out is how to get `XXXXXXX` defined.

I have 2 ideas for this.

1. Simple (I hope) increment a var starting at 49900 for each lambda function (there's about 10 at the moment, and more could be added to this project, but not enough to exhaust the port numbers).
2. Define the list of port numbers (manually defined - 1 for each lambda function) and then programmatically identify which var to use for each `lambda_$(patsubst -start-%,%,$@)`

I can hard-coded setup in the Makefile of:

```
QUEUE_PORT_NUMBER=49901
QUEUE_ADMIN_PORT_NUMBER=49902
QUEUE_API_PORT_NUMBER=49903
...
```

In playing around:

```
    LAMBDA_PORT_NUMBER_VAR_NAME=$(patsubst -start-%,%,$@)_PORT_NUMBER; echo $${LAMBDA_PORT_NUMBER_VAR_NAME^^};
```

outputs:

```
QUEUE_PORT_NUMBER
QUEUE_ADMIN_PORT_NUMBER
QUEUE_API_PORT_NUMBER
...
```

So I can programmatically define the variable that has the port number.
What I can't work out is how to take a variable with the name of a variable and then get the value from that into my recipe.

Some additional thoughts:

1. The port number is irrelevant from run to run. I'll be displaying the assigned port. I would expect them to be consistent between multiple `make start-lambdas`.
2. This is only for local devs to get the lambdas execution locally and to allow them to run tests ... all local.
3. The `docker` attach and detach already is used when we're running unit tests on each lambda in turn. This currently uses port 49990 every time. We fire a load of curl requests to the running (but detached) lambda, validate the results, and then kill the lambda, and move on to the next one. So that bit all works.

We just want to have all the lambdas up and running simultaneously.

Comment: Littering your `Makefile` with `@` is an antipattern. If you don't want to see what's happening, run it with `make -s`

Comment: @triplee, Can you refer me to anything that talks about "good" patterns for Makefile? No one is really interested in the actual command, just the output of the command. So, using `@` to suppress the command being run provides a cleaner output here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I have any immediate recommendations. I remember reading the O'Reilly book some 25+ years ago but I can't say it's particularly recommended. John Graham-Cumming's resources are probably worth looking at, but I haven't, and they might be more advanced than what you are looking for.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. You are more than welcome to post an answer of your own if you like, but your question should remain strictly a question. (The text is available from the [revision history.)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71312293/revisions)

Comment: There is a function interval in [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which generates for you a sequence of numbers like this: $(call interval,49990,$(words $(LAMBDAS)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood all details. Let's suppose you want to define a number, starting at 49901, for each of your `-start-lambda`, and that you want this number to be the same each time you invoke `make`. We can use the `join` GNU make function to assemble a list of `-start-lambda-number` tokens from your list of `-start-lambda` and a computed list of numbers. We store the list of tokens in make variable `TOKEN`.

In the following we also factorize several statements of your current Makefile with make variables (`STARTER`) and shell variables in the recipe (`lambda`). For the latter there are 2 important aspects to remember:

- make expands the recipe before passing it to the shell. So, when using the value of a shell variable we must write `$$lambda` (or `$$number`) instead of `$lambda`. After the make expansion it will become `$lambda`, what we want to pass to the shell, and no just `ambda`.
- Each line of a recipe is executed by a different shell. In order to use a shell variable in several recipe lines we must join them together with `;` (or `&&`, as you wish) such that they become one single line, executed by one single shell. But for better readability we can use the line continuation (with a trailing `\`).

The number for a given `-start-lambda` target is extracted inside the recipe and stored in a second shell variable (`number`) with `$(patsubst $@-%,%,$(filter $@-%,$(TOKEN)))`, that is, find the corresponding token with function `filter` and extract the number with `patsubst`.

```
LAMBDAS := a b c d
STARTER := $(patsubst %,-start-%,$(LAMBDAS))
NUMBER  := $(shell seq 49901 `expr 49900 + $(words $(STARTER))`)
TOKEN   := $(join $(addsuffix -,$(STARTER)),$(NUMBER))

.PHONY: start-lambdas # Get the lambdas up and running to allow you to make calls to them.

start-lambdas:
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory --makefile LastBuildMakefile report-build
    @echo ''
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory lambda-starter
    @echo ''

lambda-starter: $(STARTER)

$(STARTER):
    @lambda="$(patsubst -start-%,%,$@)"; \
    number="$(patsubst $@-%,%,$(filter $@-%,$(TOKEN)))"; \
    $(MAKE) --no-print-directory validate-lambda lambda="$$lambda"; \
    echo "Start the lambda function in lambdas/$$lambda."; \
    docker run --detach --name "lambda_$$lambda" --publish "$$number:8080" --rm "${CONTAINER_GROUP}/lambda_$$lambda:${LAST_CONTAINER_TAG_BRANCH}_${LAST_CONTAINER_TAG_VERSION}" > /dev/null
    @echo ''
```

Remember that the `$$` and the line continuations (the trailing `; \`) are essential to guarantee the proper expansion of the shell variables `lambda` and `number`, and their availability in all lines of the recipe.

Note: this works only if `$(filter $@-%,$(TOKEN)))` returns only one token. If you have two lambdas named `foo` and `foo-bar` the corresponding tokens would be, for instance, `-start-foo-49901` and `-start-foo-bar-49907` and for target `-start-foo` both would match `$@-%`. So, if you have such lambda names, change the separator between the `-start-lambda` part and the number. Use, e.g., `|` instead of `-` if you do not have `|` characters in your lambda names.

Demo with a simplified dummy example:

```
$ cat Makefile
LAMBDA  := a b c d
STARTER := $(patsubst %,-start-%,$(LAMBDA))
NUMBER  := $(shell seq 49901 `expr 49900 + $(words $(STARTER))`)
TOKEN   := $(join $(addsuffix -,$(STARTER)),$(NUMBER))

.PHONY: lambdas-starter $(STARTER)

lambda-starter: $(STARTER)

$(STARTER):
    @lambda="$(patsubst -start-%,%,$@)"; \
    number="$(patsubst $@-%,%,$(filter $@-%,$(TOKEN)))"; \
    echo "Start the lambda function in lambdas/$$lambda with $$number."

$ make
Start the lambda function in lambdas/a with 49901.
Start the lambda function in lambdas/b with 49902.
Start the lambda function in lambdas/c with 49903.
Start the lambda function in lambdas/d with 49904.
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I've taken this and reworked it for my use case (and now multiple use cases ... well ... 2 use cases!)

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Renaud Pacalet - Thank you very much.

I've taken his answer and adapted it further to my needs.

Below is one adaptation to show the list of documented Makefile targets, as well as reporting the list of lambdas and the port numbers that will be used for testing.

```
LAMBDAS := $(notdir $(wildcard ./src/lambdas/*))
PORT_NUMBERS := $(shell seq 49901 `expr 49900 + $(words $(LAMBDAS))`)
LAMBDA_TOKENS := $(join $(addsuffix -,$(LAMBDAS)),$(PORT_NUMBERS))

START_LAMBDAS := $(patsubst %,-start-%,$(LAMBDA_TOKENS))
LIST_LAMBDAS := $(patsubst %,-list-%,$(LAMBDA_TOKENS))

.PHONY: list # Generate list of targets
.PHONY: $(LIST_LAMBDAS)
list:
    @grep '^.PHONY: .* #' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | sort | sed 's/^.*\.PHONY: \(.*\) # \(.*\)/\1   \2/' | expand -t16
    @echo ''
    @echo 'The list of lambda functions known to this Makefile are:'
    @echo ''
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory list-lambdas
    @echo ''
list-lambdas:$(LIST_LAMBDAS)
$(LIST_LAMBDAS):
    @token=$(filter $(patsubst -list-%,%,$@),$(LAMBDA_TOKENS)); \
    parts=($${token//-/ }); \
    echo "  src/lambdas/$${parts[0]}    Will use port number $${parts[1]} for testing."| expand -t26
```

This outputs:

```
$ make list
build           Build the containers
list            Generate list of targets
test            Test the containers
check-container Check the version of Node in the AWS NodeJS container
clean           Remove images, logs, NodeJS cache, node_modules, and built distributions
npm-ci          Run `npm ci` for the lambda functions using the AWS NodeJS container
npm-update      Run `npm update` for the lambda functions using the AWS NodeJS container
shell           Get a bash shell prompt using the AWS NodeJS container, with the current directory mounted in /srv/queue

The list of lambda functions known to this Makefile are:

  src/lambdas/api         Will use port number 49901 for testing.
  src/lambdas/queue       Will use port number 49902 for testing.
  src/lambdas/queue_admin Will use port number 49903 for testing.
  src/lambdas/rendering   Will use port number 49904 for testing.
  src/lambdas/reporting   Will use port number 49905 for testing.
  src/lambdas/schedules   Will use port number 49906 for testing.
```

So I now have 1 pair of lambda and port numbers and then use that to build the targets for Makefile. Certainly understandable for those that can read Makefiles!